# Styling action bar tabs background with AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-tabs, android-styles

I am trying to style background for action bar for versions 2.2 >=. I want to have dark red on title bar and lighter red on tabs. I have similar file placed in values-v11 and values-v14 accordingly. It works as intended on ICS and Kitkat I tested. On 2.x, the color on backgroundStacked appears on both the title bar and tabs.

Why is this happening? I don't want to use Android Asset Studio because I don't want to add extra images if it is possible without.

`res/values/styles.xml`

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@color/dark_red</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@color/lighter_red</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```